# c++ stdout string to JSON in Node.js

Tags: c++, node.js, child-process

What i'm doing is making  a little process interface using node.js
I have a child process spawned and it returns some strings on stdout like this

```
'head' : 'this is the head'
```

I get that string from stdout in node, and then I want to JSON.parse() it to turn it into a 'JSON object', so I can treat the response like a variable line,

```
var thing = data.name // this should assign thing the string 'value'
```

the problem: 
node crashes

```
undefined:1
'name' : 'value'
^
```

the node part:

```
proc = spawn(data.command)

proc.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  var res = data.toString()
  socket.emit('echo', res )
  console.log( JSON.parse(res) )
})
```

the .cpp part

```
cout << "'name' : 'value'" << endl;
```

EDIT: also, how would i compose a large json object, with multiple name value pairs from 1 cout?

Comment: this is not json? http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp